# Mars Semi Direct

Tags: mars, nasa, spacex, crewed-spaceflight

I looked at a presentation of Robert Zubrin. In this presentation, he first about his (old) Mars Direct plan, then he talks a bit about Mars Semi Direct with the Falcon Heavy Rocket. He want to use every two years three of them.

So, does someone know a **link**, which has some **details** about this plan?

Comment: What have your Web searches brought you?

Comment: I've only found this, it is the right version but this link is with the Magnum rocket, which can fly up to 80 mt to LEO. link; http://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/trs/_techrep/SP-6107-ADD.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a good question. So not really a good answer.

Here is [a great presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKQSijn9FBs) Zubrin did, where he discusses Mars Direct / Semi Direct. Very compelling discussion:

Video was recorded in July 10, 2014 during the NASA Ames Research Center Director's Colloquium at Moffett Field, California. Here are some numbers for the Semi Direct plan, pulled from the video ([roughly 29 minutes into it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=EKQSijn9FBs#t=1724)):

[image]

Zubrin commented that the margins for this Mars Semi Direct are tight, but doable with water recycling that is the key to payload mass savings.

---

Some additional sources to consider:

- The [Mars Direct Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Direct) is pretty good.
- Nice [Mars Direct article from 1996](http://www.nss.org/settlement/mars/zubrin-promise.html) (Pre-Falcon Heavy).
- [2009 Presentation that was used in the video](http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/376589main_04%20-%20Mars%20Direct%20Power%20Point-7-30-09.pdf), for the Mars Direct part.  Still no Falcon Heavy version in it.
- Jeff Foust (Space Review) has a nice 2011 article on [Mars Semi-Direct using Falcon Heavy](http://www.thespacereview.com/article/1850/1).

Comment: Because of this video I wrote this question.. I saw it and then I wanted to know more about this plan.

Comment: Thanks for the Powerpoint, but I actually search an article about technicals informations such as the mass .. (sorry I didn't say it exactly)

Comment: @mars72 Have you read the Case for Mars? Same basic idea, just scaled down as low as you can go to do it on Falcon Heavy. Honestly, I do not think Zubrin has very specific numbers on it, lots of handwaving, but eneough to make it seem maybe plausible.

Comment: I see a large white space in the middle of the answer. Is that intentional? I'm guessing there's a problem with the video.

Comment: @HDE226868 A new site feature has been implemented [on our request](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/572/49), to be able to embed videos in posts. If you're experiencing "mixed contents" issues (mixing HTTPS and HTTP accessed contents on page might trigger different browser warnings), then please enable mixed contents for [se] for the time being. In Firefox, for example, there's a gray "shield" icon in the address bar through which you can opt to display mixed contents here. I asked [se] developers to fix this and remove protocol dependencies in embedded videos (i.e. go protocol-less).